# How to display placeholders in AngularJS for undefined expression values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, placeholder

If I have an expression `{{ x }}` and x is `undefined` or `null`, then how can I display a placeholder for it?

I provided one solution in my answer, but I would like to know what other ways there are.
Maybe, also for placeholder for promises.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`{{ counter || '?'}}`.
Just pure javascript. `||` can be used as default value. Since it would be different empty messages in each, a generalized directive would not be suitable for many cases.

If you want to apply a different class to empty ones, that's also built-in:

```
<div ng-class="{empty: !counter}" ng-bind="counter || ?"></div>
```

Comment: FWIW, make sure to put the default value before any filters (e.g. `{{ counter || '?' | myfilter }}`).

Comment: This answer is simple and clean, but the drawback is that it will not only display the placeholder on `null` and `undefined`, but also on `0`, which can be a valid value.

Answer (score 25):

I would do it like this, but maybe there is a better way:

```
angular.module('app').filter('placeholdEmpty', function(){
  return function(input){
    if(!(input == undefined || input == null)){
      return input;
    } else {
      return "placeholder";
    }
  }
});
```

and then use `{{ x | placeholdEmpty}}`

Comment: The advantage of the filter solution over {{ counter || '?'}} is that you can distinguish between undefined, null or zero.

Comment: Another important advantage of placeholder filter is that in future, you can easily change the placeholder text, if you decide that you dont like '?'...

Comment: And how do you apply a filter to x?

Comment: @JustGoscha ..Works Perfect..Thanks

Comment: This filter doesn't allow to provide the default without modifying the filter. Look at @naXa answer below.

Answer (score 13):

I do it with ng-show, like this:

```
<strong>{{username}}</strong>
<span class="empty" ng-show="!username">N/A</span>
```

Sure, it adds a lot more elements to my view that I might be able to handle differently. I like though how easy it is to clearly see where my placeholder/empty values are, and I can style them differently as well.

Answer (score 5):

Implement `default` filter:

```
app.filter('default', function(){
  return function(value, def) {
    return (value === undefined || value === null? def : value);
  };
});
```

And use it as:

```
{{ x | default: '?' }}
```

The advantage of the filter solution over `{{ x || '?'}}` is that you can distinguish between `undefined`, `null` or `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing default-ish filters works, but if you're using only numbers you can use angular's own [number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

> If the input is null or undefined, it will just be returned. If the
>   input is infinite (Infinity or -Infinity), the Infinity symbol '∞' or
>   '-∞' is returned, respectively. If the input is not a number an empty
>   string is returned.

```
{{ (val | number ) || "Number not provided"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works with ng-bind="(val | number) || 'Default'" as well!