# AngularJS - filter for undefined properties in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For my AngularJS project (v1.2.3), I have a list of routes and am trying to build a navigation bar from the object.  What I want to do is display any object with an undefined `isRight` property in one style, and where the property is defined in another.

In one `ng-repeat` I would like to filter those objects with an undefined `isRight` property.  How can I accomplish this inside the `ng-repeat` attribute, without having to resort to creating a custom filter function?

```
$scope.nav = [
    { path: '/', title: 'Home' },
    { path: '/blog', title: 'Blog' },
    { path: '/about', title: 'About' },
    { path: '/login', title: 'Login', isRight: true }
];
```

I realize I could just add the attribute `isRight: false` to each object, or have separate nav objects for right and left side links, and other such simple workarounds, but I am curious if there is a way to accomplish this with the current structure, using something along the lines of:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:undefined}">
```

This is more a curiosity than a need, but I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Had the same issue. I used `prop: undefined` to filter for when the property didn't have a value, and `prop: {}` for when the property was an object. The problem is that neither of these included when the property was missing. Thanks for asking this question that helped me find the magic `!` and `!!`!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can negate a filter expression.  So instead of dealing with `undefined` you can just filter out anything where `isRight` is not (`!`) true.  Like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:'!true'} ">
```

And for the opposite you can, of course, do:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:'true'} ">
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nPyj/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I tried a similar thing many times, but was placing the negation everywhere but **inside** the quotations.  A simple `ng-if` was the only way I accomplished it previously.

Comment: edit: Even so, I do wish there was something a bit more elegant, which gives the impression that a property could be undefined and not simply `!true` or `false`.

Comment: Yea, might be worth putting a comment there making it clear that the !true case it meant to catch nav elements where `isRight` is undefined.

Answer (score 44):

You can also use
`<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:'!'}">`

see also [How to display placeholders in AngularJS for undefined expression values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658535/how-to-display-placeholders-in-angularjs-for-undefined-expression-values)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope' , function($scope) {


$scope.nav = [
    { path: '/', title: 'Home' },
    { path: '/blog', title: 'Blog' },
    { path: '/about', title: 'About' },
    { path: '/login', title: 'Login', isRight: true }
];
  
}])
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<h3>!isRight</h3>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:'!'}">{{link.title}}</li>
</ul>
  
  
<h3>isRight</h3>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:{isRight:'!!'}">{{link.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the real deal baby

Comment: Nice one! Needed to filter out objects that don't have the `id` property and doing the following worked like a treat: `ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter: { id: '!!' }`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, should be ranked higher!

Comment: Sweet mother of loosely-typed languages

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

I just reread the question, and this is not the answer you are looking for.  I will leave it here for documentation purposes, but I do not think there is a way to get the functionality you desire without either building a custom filter or using a custom filter function.

To expand on why looking for undefined will not work with the default filter we take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L177) code from the AngularJS `filter` implementation.

```
switch (typeof expression) {
  ...
  case "object":
    // jshint +W086
    for (var key in expression) {
      (function(path) {
        if (typeof expression[path] == 'undefined') return;
        predicates.push(function(value) {
          return search(path == '$' ? value : getter(value, path), expression[path]);
        });
      })(key);
    }
    break;
  ...
}
```

If a value for the filter object's property is `undefined`, no predicate function is added to the predicates array.  In your case you are setting the value of the `isRight` property to `undefined` (your filter expression is `{isRight:undefined}`).

**Original Answer**

You can always use a predicate function to create arbitrary filters ([documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/docs/api/ng.filter:filter)).

> A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The
>   function is called for each element of array. The final result is an
>   array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

In your controller create a method to pick the items you want

```
$scope.isRightUndefined = function(item) {
  return item.isRight === undefined;
}
```

and change your repeat to be

```
<li ng-repeat="link in nav | filter:isRightUndefined">
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but yes, not one I was hoping for.  I also believe in leaving answers for documentation that others can stumble upon, and even leaving answers after one has been accepted.  Currently, I am using the solution from @KayakDave.

Comment: Your original answers actually seems to be working for me in Angular 1.2.1: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg8kF/90/

Answer (score 4):

```
module.filter('notNullOrUndefined', [function () {
    return function (items, property) {
        var arrayToReturn = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var test = property !== undefined ? items[i][property] : items[i];
            if (test !== undefined && test !== null) {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="style in styles | notNullOrUndefined:'background'">
    <span class="ed-item">{{style.name}} Background</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code - it will be useful next time i need something like this.  however, my original question was how to accomplish something like this without having to resort to custom filters.